# Getting SqlCeException on restart if I don't insert data to the DB

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, exception, sql-server-ce

Basically, I have a LINQ database context and its model. As usually, I create the DB in the SQL context if the DB does not exist (the context is a singleton and on every access to it, this is checked).

Everything works well if I add data to the DB on the first launch. But if I don't insert any data during the first start of the app, on successive launches I get

> SqlCeException:The specified table does not exist [TableName]

I don't know how more specifically I can explain it, but the exception comes immediately whenever I do a LINQ query **on the second launch of the app if I don't insert any data on the first launch**. If i do insert some data during the first launch, all is fine for the rest of the app's life time. Why would it be a bad thing to create the DBs and introduce the DB context, but not insert any data?

Here's my LINQ DB model:

- https://github.com/kypeli/Podcatcher/blob/master/wp7/Podcatcher/ViewModels/PodcastSubscriptionModel.cs

Here's where I get the exception on second start if I didn't insert any data on the first launch:

- https://github.com/kypeli/Podcatcher/blob/master/wp7/Podcatcher/PodcastSqlModel.cs#L64

It also strikes me that there's no API call to check if a table exists or not in LINQ, so I would have to assume "this should just work" - but it doesn't.

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

**Update:** I verified analyzing the .sdf file that indeed there are no tables created if I don't insert any data upon first launch of the app. As I see it:

- **This is a bug in LINQ-to-SQL**. It should not crash if there are no tables present, but know that it should create them. Or deal with the case and create tables only when data is inserted.
- I would need to insert some dummy data into SQL always on first launch, or...
- Check if a table exists, if not, react to it by forcing LINQ-to-SQL to create them. But how?

Comment: I did some digging. I downloaded the .sdf file off the device and analyzed it with SQL Compact Query Analyzer. I fact, the tables are not created to SQL if I don't insert any data, so I get an error after second launch. If I do insert data, then tables are there. Seems odd to me that there are no tables even if CreateDatabase() is called. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure how Linq to SQL differs in WP7, but it's possible you might need to call SubmitChanges after CreateDatabase is called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I did try that as well with no help.

Comment: What if you dispose the DataContext/close the connection immediately after creating the database? I'm thinking that SQL CE might not have flushed the changes to the file, so it could just be sitting on in-memory changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this problem also, I've fixed it this way:

get the data context:

```
dbDataContext = new DBDataContext(DBConnectionString);

if( dbDataContext.DatabaseExists() == true)
```

//then try to get an entity:

```
System.Data.Linq.Table<Entity> entities = dbDataContext.Tablename;
```

//try to get an element from the entity:

```
IEnumerator<Entity> enumEntity = entities.GetEnumerator();
```

`entities.GetEnumerator();` will always raise the exception "Table not found."

Just use a try/catch and in the catch scope delete the db and recreate it, because your DB is empty anyway :)

```
dbDataContext.DeleteDatabase();
dbDataContext.CreateDatabase();
dbDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vlad for your reply! I will try out your solution in a bit later, but sounds like this would work! :) And it sure sounds like a bug that MS should be aware of... :-/ So frustrating. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, this solved the issue! Still, to me, this sounds like a bug in LINQ-to-SQL on Windows Phone 7.5.

Comment: For the curios ones, this is my code that fixed the issue: https://github.com/kypeli/Podcatcher/commit/7ebf8d7568fd1d92db8ff1e93f256e4d45605723